# Create a Function that Returns John Daniel Dec 6th 2009

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to create a Function that would concatenate the first name last name and birth date to be displayed as "Marc Smith Dec 6th, 2009" I have finally been able to play around with the function enough that it executes correctly, but I'm when I select the function I get an error. Please let me know if this is an accurate function and what should be selected to get the desired output.

```
CREATE TABLE Info (
First_name VARCHAR(32),
Last_name VARCHAR(32),
Birth DATE);


INSERT INTO Info (First_name, Last_name, Birth) VALUES ('Marc', 'Smith', '2009-12-06');


DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION bdate(
First_Name VARCHAR(32)
Last_Name VARCHAR(32),
Birth DATE))
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)

BEGIN

DECLARE bdate VARCHAR(64);

SET bdate = (SELECT CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name, ' ', DATE_FORMAT(Birth, '%b %D, %Y')) FROM Info);                
RETURN bdate();

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

> Schema Error: Error: ER_SP_NO_RECURSION: Recursive stored functions and triggers are not allowed.

Comment: Why didn't you use bdate instead First_name for setting the concatenated text?

Comment: I thought if I had set the first name as the concatenated and I selected a specific name such as SELECT bdate(Marc); it would give me the desired outcome but it hasn't. I changed it to bdate and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some errors.

You called in the return again the function. using _bdate circumwendts tht problem.
You had also a bracket too much

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION bdate(
First_Name VARCHAR(32),
Last_Name VARCHAR(32),
Birth DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(64)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE _bdate VARCHAR(64);

SET _bdate = (SELECT CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name, ' ', DATE_FORMAT(Birth, '%b %D, %Y'))   FROM Info);                
RETURN _bdate;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

> SELECT bdate('Marc', 'Smith', '2009-12-06');

Returns

> Marc Smith Dec 6th, 2009

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the local variable. Also the max length should be longer than 64

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION bdate(
First_Name VARCHAR(32),
Last_Name VARCHAR(32),
Birth DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(80)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN CONCAT(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name, ' ', DATE_FORMAT(Birth, '%b %D, %Y'));                
END //

DELIMITER ;
SELECT bdate('Marc', 'Smith', '2009-12-06') AS bd;
```